# Spinner Visibility

Tags: android, android-layout, spinner

I've a strange problem with my custom spinner. My implementation is to hide the spinner and only fire the choices whenever i click a button so my spinner visibility is set to INVISIBLE and only fire a list of choices and assign the selected value back to a TextView. My code works only in emulator but when i went to my actual device the list of choices is not opened and only the default value is selected back to my textview. I've tried to set spinner visibility to Visible. This time i got the choices. I remember i have another implementation with the visibility is set to INVISIBLE and it worked as desired. Any clues?

XML Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#EEE8E0"
android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="100" >

<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="#E69100" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="100"
        android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/attach4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/attach" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/attach3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/attach" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/attach2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/attach" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/attach1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/attach" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true" >

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:background="#222222"
                android:visibility="invisible" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/addtitle"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/selecttype"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edittextback"
                android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
                android:hint="عنوان الأعلان"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:lines="1"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:textColor="#444545"
                android:textSize="17dp" >
            </EditText>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/addbrief"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/addtitle"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edittextback"
                android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
                android:hint="المواصفات"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:lines="4"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:textColor="#444545"
                android:textSize="17dp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/addprice"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/addbrief"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edittextback"
                android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
                android:hint="السعر"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:textColor="#444545"
                android:textSize="17dp" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/addmoney"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/addbrief"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/addprice"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/addprice"
                android:background="@drawable/edittextback"
                android:entries="@array/country_arrays"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:prompt="@string/country_prompt"
                android:textColor="#444545"
                android:textSize="17dp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/addkilometrage"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/addprice"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/addprice"
                android:layout_below="@+id/addprice"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edittextback"
                android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
                android:hint="المسافة المقطوعة"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:textColor="#444545"
                android:textSize="17dp" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/addkilo"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/addmoney"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/addkilometrage"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/addprice"
                android:background="@drawable/edittextback"
                android:entries="@array/kilo"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:prompt="@string/country_prompt"
                android:textColor="#444545"
                android:textSize="17dp" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/Spinner01"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/addkilo"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/addkilometrage"
                android:layout_below="@+id/addkilometrage"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edittextback"
                android:entries="@array/year"
                android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:prompt="@string/country_prompt"
                android:textColor="#444545"
                android:textSize="17dp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/EditText01"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Spinner01"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/Spinner01"
                android:layout_below="@+id/Spinner01"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edittextback"
                android:ems="10"
                android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
                android:hint="رقم الهاتف/الجوال"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:lines="1"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:textColor="#444545"
                android:textSize="17dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/continueregist"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/EditText01"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/addprice"
                android:layout_below="@+id/EditText01"
                android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
                android:background="@drawable/green_buttons"
                android:text="Continue"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="19dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner_type"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
                android:visibility="invisible" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner_model"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
                android:visibility="invisible" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/selecttype"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/addtitle"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/sell" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textcattype"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/spinner_type"
                android:layout_marginRight="21dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/selecttype"
                android:text=""
                android:textSize="19dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/selectmodel"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/addmoney"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/selecttype"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/buy" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textcarmodel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/selectmodel"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/selectmodel"
                android:text=""
                android:textSize="19dp" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainaddshekh"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#222222"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</RelativeLayout>
```

Java Class:

```
public class Sell_Class extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

Spinner Type, Model;
MyAdapter adapter1;
MyAdapter2 adapter2;
EditText cartypeedit;
ImageView cartype, carmodel;
TextView cartypetext, carmodeltext;

String CarType="",CarModel;

int arr_images[] = {

R.drawable.hy,

R.drawable.hy

};

final String[] CarsType = new String[] {

"هيونداي", "هوندا",

};

final String[] Hyundai = new String[] {

"أكسنت", "أكسيل"

};

final String[] Honda = new String[] {

"أكورد", "سيفيك",

};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mainsell);

    Type = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_type);
    Model = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_model);

    cartype = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.selecttype);
    carmodel = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.selectmodel);

    cartypetext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textcattype);
    carmodeltext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textcarmodel);

    cartype.setOnClickListener(this);
    carmodel.setOnClickListener(this);

    Type.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {


              // get spinner value

                cartypetext.setText(CarsType[arg2]);
                CarType = CarsType[arg2];
                CarModel="";
                carmodeltext.setText("");





        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {


        }

    });

    Model.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {




                if (CarType.contentEquals("هيونداي")) {

                    carmodeltext.setText(Hyundai[arg2]);
                    CarModel = Hyundai[arg2];
                }

                if (CarType.contentEquals("هوندا")) {

                    carmodeltext.setText(Honda[arg2]);
                    CarModel = Honda[arg2];

                }



        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    });

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {

    case R.id.selecttype:

        adapter1 = new MyAdapter(this, CarsType, arr_images);

        Type.setAdapter(adapter1);

        Type.performClick();

        cartypetext.setText("");


        break;

    case R.id.selectmodel:

        if (CarType.contentEquals("")) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Please select car first", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        else

        {
            if (CarType.contentEquals("هيونداي")) {

                adapter2 = new MyAdapter2(Sell_Class.this, Hyundai);

                Model.setAdapter(adapter2);

                Model.performClick();
                carmodeltext.setText("");

            }

            if (CarType.contentEquals("هوندا")) {

                adapter2 = new MyAdapter2(Sell_Class.this, Honda);

                Model.setAdapter(adapter2);

                Model.performClick();

                carmodeltext.setText("");

            }


        }

        break;

    }

}

}
```

MyAdapter:

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Context c;
String[] title;
int[] pic;
LayoutInflater inflater;
Typeface font;

int arr_images[] = { 

    R.drawable.hy,

    R.drawable.hy

         };



public MyAdapter(Context context, String[] title, int[] pic) {
    super();
    this.c = context;
    this.title = title;
    this.pic = pic;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

 //   font = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"fonts/khalaadsara.ttf");

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return title.length;
}

public class ViewHolder {
    TextView cat;
    ImageView icon;

}
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView== null) {

        holder = new ViewHolder();

        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinnertext, null);

    holder.cat = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.titlesub);
    holder.icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.cat.setText(title[position]);
//  holder.cat.setTypeface(font);
    holder.icon.setImageResource(arr_images[position]);

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}


}
```

Comment: Post the relevant code and we can probably give better help

Comment: It would be easier if you could cut down on some of the code and explain the problem a little more clearly

Comment: I don't see any visibility changes in the code. Where do you set the View's visibility state ? what is the problem ? make it more clear.

Comment: I don't change the spinner's visibility. As far as i know when we set the spinner to Invisible (field perspective) we can still open it's list of choices at anytime by .performclick (even it's invisible).

Comment: if (CarType.contentEquals("xxx")) {

                adapter2 = new MyAdapter2(Sell_Class.this, Honda);

                Model.setAdapter(adapter2);

                Model.performClick();

                carmodeltext.setText("");

            }

Comment: But this works fine in Emulator only. When i go to my actual device the pop up choices doesn't appear at all with the butotn click.